# how does rstudio choose which files to open on startup/ when a project closes

Tags: r, rstudio

There isn't any code associated with this question but still a programming related question.

When I open RStudio my previous R files that I worked on are displayed in the source viewer (as expected). Sometimes when I open two R sessions another set of programs will be displayed (or when I exit out of an R project different R files will be shown after I am out of the project). My question is how does RStudio determine what files to open? Particularly how does it store this information when you have multiple sessions open at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location will vary depending on if one is viewing a project vs not viewing a project and Windows vs Non-Windows OS.

## No Project

### Windows

On my Win10 machine, such information is stored in `file.path(Sys.getenv("localappdata"), "RStudio-Desktop", "sources")`.

When an instance of RStudio is open, references to the open sources are stored in a directory matching the following regex `^[a-z]{1}-[A-Z0-9]{8}$`; an example being: `s-9BDA15C3`.

Another instance of RStudio will correspond to a similarly named directory in the same location.

When RStudio is closed, the corresponding directory is removed and its contents are copied to `file.path(Sys.getenv("localappdata"), "RStudio-Desktop", "sources", "per", "t")`.

### Non-Windows

On a non-windows machine, I expect a similar configuration would be located in `file.path("~", "RStudio-Desktop", "sources")`.

## Projects

When in a project (regardless of OS), this data is likely stored in `file.path(rstudioapi::getActiveProject(), ".Rproj.user", "^[A-Z0-9]{8}$", "sources")`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be changed/set in RStudio > Tools > Options > General
Under R sessions the two "restore" options are checked by default.
support.rstudio.com has info on this